# Can one add headers to a redirect with Grails

Tags: http, grails

I have files on a CDN stored using arbitrary file names. When requests for certain files are made to my application, I want to redirect (302) to the URLs of the files on the CDN. However, I want to add response headers to the resulting request. Specifically, I want to add content type, disposition, and fileName=. Is this possible using Grails?

**Edit: This is what I would like/expect to work**

```
class SomeController {
    def someAction() {
        String cdnFileUrl = "http://somecdn.com/foo.bin"

        response.status = HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND
        response.setHeader('Location', cdnFileUrl)
        response.setContentType('application/octet-stream')
        response.setHeader('content-disposition', 'filename=bar.bin')
        render('')
    }
}
```

The redirect occurs, and the cdnFile is served, however the response does not contain the 'Location' and 'content-disposition'. The content type is text/pain, but that is what I would expect from somecdn.com as it appears to be always setting it as such.

Comment: I think you should be able to add whatever custom headers you want to the response, given that you handle the request in your code

Comment: I've tried mucking with the response. Specifically setting the status to 302/Found, the content type and and disposition, and the Location to the CDN url. The 'redirect' works, but the headers don't seem to be applied to the resulting request.

Comment: any luck with the solution?

Comment: Any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In Grails you've got [response](http://grails.org/doc/2.2.1/ref/Servlet%20API/response.html) object in controllers which is an instance of [HttpServletResponse](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletResponse.html) with methods like setHeader(String, String) etc.

Comment: I've added a comment to the question that describes my attempts with the response.